# Stuck using an array in the constructor as a parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to this and I am having a problem. I want to use an array as a parameter in the constructor, but when I want to initialize the parameter in the `main()` function and call the class, it seems I can't directly put the array values as I did with the `name` and `surname`. The simplified code looks like below. It shows an error that the default constructor is not available.

```
class Student {
private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int age;
    int grade[5];
public:
    Student(string e, string b, int c,int A[5]) {
        name = e;
        surname = b;
        age = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            grade[i] = A[i];

    }
};

int main() {
    Student obj = Student("Jack","blalba", 18, {10,10,9,8,8});
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array`, not C-style arrays, then your parameter becomes assignable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be changed is the [constructor](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mU6IqSJ7EKsVORx4):

```
Student(string e, string b, int c, int (&&A)[5]) {
        name = e;
        surname = b;
        age = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            grade[i] = A[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Student(string e, string b, int c,int A[5])
```

There's no such thing as a function, method, or a constructor parameter that's an array. Array cannot be functions parameters, C++ simply does not work this way.

You can write such a declaration, but what happens is that the parameter gets converted to a pointer. The above declaration is logically equivalent to:

```
     Student(string e, string b, int c,int *A)
```

And now the reason for your compilation error is very obvious:

```
Student obj = Student("Jack","blalba", 18, {10,10,9,8,8});
```

The expression `{10, 10, 9, 8, 8}` cannot be converted to an `int *` in C++.

The simplest solution is to pass it explicitly as an array:

```
int a[5]={10,10,9,8,8};
Student obj = Student("Jack","blalba", 18, a);
```

It should also be possible to use a `std::initializer_list`, but that would be more complicated than needed.

Comment: "*The simplest solution is to pass it explicitly as an array*" - Or, to use `std::array` instead.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot have an array as a parameter? If you just do `#include <array>` and then `int foo(array<int, 5> bar)` isn't it just that?

Comment: Yep, the answer is not of the highest quality, but neither is the question.

Comment: You can have an array as a function arg. `f(int a[5]){..}` works fine

Comment: @pm100 That's true, but it doesn't mean what some people (beginners) take it to mean.